# Why cant I iterate over this JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript object..

```
var obj = {
    '02/08/2016': 2,
    '03/10/2016': 4,
    '04/05/2016': 2,
    '04/06/2016': 35,
    '04/19/2016': 4,
    '04/26/2016': 22,
    '05/09/2016': 15,
    '05/24/2016': 2,
    '05/30/2016': 4,
    '07/14/2016': 7,
    '08/18/2016': 200
};

// Does not work
$(obj).each(function(index,value) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(value);
});

// Does not work, also what does putting it in bracket notation do here?
var labels = $.map(obj, function(index, value) { 
   return [index];  
});
```

Why can I not iterate the object? I am trying to place this data in two separate arrays (like below) for chart.js

```
var arr1 = ['02/08/2016', '03/10/2016', '04/05/2016', ..];
var arr2 = [2, 4, 2, ...];
```

Code Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjgb6ez4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, your code should be [`$.each(obj, callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback)

Comment: @4castle How does that differ from $(obj).each? Arent both jQuery?

Comment: @NightOwl4Life: Didn't you just cite the jQuery docs about this in another comment?

Comment: `$()` is only for selecting DOM elements.

Comment: Why do you have an object instead of an array? That seems like the logical structure to use here.

Comment: @DavidG Can you see me secondary question, just edited.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life You can't keep changing your question - just stick with the original please and if you have a follow up, ask another question.

Comment: @DavidG party pooper :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your logic is, `$.each()` has two signatures:

```
$(selector).each(function(index,value) {...} // For HTML DOM selectors.
$.each(obj, function(index,value) {...}      // For JavaScript Objects & Arrays.
```

What you have used is for jQuery selectors, DOM Iteration. This way is specifically for iterating JavaScript Objects or Arrays.

Also, since you need two arrays. You can't use `each` or `map` function for this, as they return only one array. Instead, it is better to use `Object.keys` and `Object.values()`:

```js
var obj = {
    '02/08/2016': 2,
    '03/10/2016': 4,
    '04/05/2016': 2,
    '04/06/2016': 35,
    '04/19/2016': 4,
    '04/26/2016': 22,
    '05/09/2016': 15,
    '05/24/2016': 2,
    '05/30/2016': 4,
    '07/14/2016': 7,
    '08/18/2016': 200
};
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
var arr2 = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

> **Note:** [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is an experimental technology. Because this technology's specification has not stabilised, check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behaviour of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.

**Without `Object.values()`**

```js
var obj = {
    '02/08/2016': 2,
    '03/10/2016': 4,
    '04/05/2016': 2,
    '04/06/2016': 35,
    '04/19/2016': 4,
    '04/26/2016': 22,
    '05/09/2016': 15,
    '05/24/2016': 2,
    '05/30/2016': 4,
    '07/14/2016': 7,
    '08/18/2016': 200
};
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
var arr2 = arr1.map(function (v) {
  return obj[v];
});
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: how come I cannot? 

From the JQuery Doc's
"The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object."

Comment: @NightOwl4Life Run the above snippet and tell me if it works?

Comment: @NightOwl4Life You are right, but there are better ways of doing it. You really can't do with `map` function at least. Sorry to be unclear.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, how does this work exactly? Not a problem, this has been a frustrating learning experience and I have encountered it quite a few times.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life `Object.keys()` is a native function that gives you the keys as array. `Object.values()` is a native function that gives you the values as array.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life What you have used is for jQuery selectors, DOM Iteration. This way is specifically for iterating JavaScript Objects or Arrays.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life Also, it is better to do in the right way unless you need to use `$.each()` as a requirement. Internally, `$.each` runs both `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to get your iterate over this.

Comment: You might want to add that `Object.values()` is not officially released yet and that not all browsers support it.

Comment: @FelixKling How does it look now?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes

Comment: @NightOwl4Life Added another snippet, that gives you the better compatible version. Have a look please.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life Should I answer the secondary question or is it clear?

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery to iterate over a plain object you need to use `$.each()`.

```
$.each(obj, function(index,value) {...}
```

A pure Javascript solution might be:

```
for (var index in obj) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(obj[index]);
}
```

Comment: Does this differ from $(obj).each(function(index,value)?

Comment: @NightOwl4Life What you have used is for jQuery selectors, DOM Iteration. This way is specifically for iterating JavaScript Objects or Arrays.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life you dont need the selector - you already have the data you need

Comment: @NightOwl4Life, yes, this is the right answer. Two each() methods: https://api.jquery.com/each/  and: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @PraveenKumar That completely clears it up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keys()` and `values()` methods on `Object`.

```
var obj = {
    '02/08/2016': 2,
    '03/10/2016': 4,
    '04/05/2016': 2,
    '04/06/2016': 35,
    '04/19/2016': 4,
    '04/26/2016': 22,
    '05/09/2016': 15,
    '05/24/2016': 2,
    '05/30/2016': 4,
    '07/14/2016': 7,
    '08/18/2016': 200
};
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
var arr2 = Object.values(obj);
```

This is plain JavaScript solution, without jQuery. But note that `values()` method is not supported in all browsers yet.

Comment: I had no idea those methods existed, unfortunately I still get [0] and [object].

Comment: @NightOwl4Life fixed it.

Comment: @NightOwl4Life I updated my answer, please recheck. By the way this pure JavaScript, without jQuery.

Comment: You might want to add that `Object.values()` is not officially released yet and that not all browsers support it.